# (DONE) Why was "Our top dev doesn't want new challenges" closed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Our top dev doesn't want new challenges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/157438/our-top-dev-doesnt-want-new-challenges)

This question was closed as off-topic with the reasoning "Questions require a goal that we can address..."

Yet it had 12 good answers! Clearly at least 12 people were able to find a goal that they were capable of addressing.

I don't understand how someone could read it and not find a goal.

I voted to reopen it. I ask that others do, too.

Comment: I think this question is not "(DONE)" until the people that closed it give an answer on why it was closed? It was a pretty good and original question about something that does happen in many workplaces. So, why was it posted, closed and reopened all in 48 hours?

Comment: @teego1967 - people who voted to close already selected a reason for closing. "Questions require a goal that we can address...". I wouldn't expect anything more than that.

Comment: I think your initial impulse to question the closing still stands. Selecting an option from a radio-button doesn't constitute an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I wish it had more focus and less poetry, **i vote to re-open**

I wish someone (OP?) would add a summary header, perhaps something like:

> one of the devs is busy up to the brim, don't want extra responsibility. How to manage the situation?

Comment: "I wish someone (OP?) would add a summary header," - done